# My form is not doing the POST (React, MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, forms, post

I am doing a React project in which I need to send data to a MongoDB database, until now I have the following code, and, because I am new to React and databases, I have not been able to find out why the to submit button does not do any action.(I will try to show the code as summarized as possible)

```
const projectSchema = yup.object().shape({
  project_start: yup
    .date()
    .nullable()
    .min(new Date(), "Start Date must be later than today"),
  project_end: yup
    .date()
    .nullable()
    .min(new Date(), "End Date must be later than today"),
  project_name: yup.string().required("required"),
  usersId: yup.array().of(yup.string()),
  partnerId: yup.string(),
  categoryId: yup.string(),
});

const initialValuesProject = {
  project_start: null,
  project_end: null,
  project_name: "",
  usersId: [],
  partnerId: "",
  categoryId: "",
};

/*(...)*/

const Calendar = () => {

/*(...)*/

const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState([]);

/*(...)*/

const { data } = useGetAllUsersQuery();
  const { data: data2 } = useGetPartnerQuery();
  const { data: data3 } = useGetCategoriesQuery();

  const postProject = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    // this allows us to send form info with image
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value in values) {
      formData.append(value, values[value]);
    }

    const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:5001/client/projects",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    savedUserResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    await postProject(values, onSubmitProps);
  };

/*(...)*/

return (

/*(...)*/

<Formik
          onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
          initialValues={initialValuesProject}
          validationSchema={projectSchema}
        >
          {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "50%",
                  left: "50%",
                  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                  width: 500,
                  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.alt,
                  border: "2px solid #000",
                  boxShadow: 24,
                  p: 4,
                }}
              >
                <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h4" component="h2">
                  Nuevo Proyecto
                </Typography>
                <Box mt="2rem" display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
                  <Box>
                    <Typography mt="0.5rem" variant="body1">
                      Fecha de inicio:
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography mt="2rem" variant="body1">
                      Fecha final esperado:
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography mt="2rem" variant="body1">
                      Nombre del proyecto:
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography mt="2rem" variant="body1">
                      Encargado:
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography mt="2rem" variant="body1">
                      Socio:
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography mt="2rem" variant="body1">
                      Categoría:
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                  <Box width="50%">
                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                      <DatePicker
                        id="project_start"
                        name="project_start"
                        value={values.project_start}
                        onChange={(value) =>
                          setFieldValue("project_start", value, true)
                        }
                        slotProps={{
                          textField: {
                            size: "small",
                            margin: "dense",
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                      <DatePicker
                        id="project_end"
                        name="project_end"
                        value={values.project_end}
                        onChange={(value) =>
                          setFieldValue("project_end", value, true)
                        }
                        renderValue={(selected) => {
                          return [{ selected }];
                        }}
                        slotProps={{
                          textField: { size: "small", margin: "dense" },
                        }}
                      />
                    </LocalizationProvider>
                    <TextField id="nombreP" margin="dense" size="small" />
                    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                      <Select
                        id="encargadoP"
                        multiple
                        name="usersId"
                        value={values.usersId}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        MenuProps={MenuProps}
                        renderValue={(selected) => (
                          <Box
                            sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}
                          >
                            {selected.map((value) => (
                              <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                            ))}
                          </Box>
                        )}
                        sx={{ width: 205 }}
                      >
                        {data?.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                          <MenuItem key={_id} value={name}>
                            {name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                      <Select
                        id="partnerP"
                        name="partnerId"
                        value={values.partnerId}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        MenuProps={MenuProps}
                        sx={{ width: 205 }}
                      >
                        {data2?.map(({ _id, partner_name }) => (
                          <MenuItem key={_id} value={partner_name}>
                            {partner_name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                      <Select
                        id="categoryP"
                        name="categoryId"
                        value={values.categoryId}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        MenuProps={MenuProps}
                        sx={{ width: 205 }}
                      >
                        {data3?.map(({ _id, category_name }) => (
                          <MenuItem key={_id} value={category_name}>
                            {category_name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant={"outlined"}
                  size={"large"}
                  sx={{
                    width: 420,
                    border: "1px solid white",
                    m: "3rem 0 0 0",
                    color: "white",
                    borderRadius: "30px",
                  }}
                >
                  Agregar proyecto
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>

/*(...)*/

);
};
export default Calendar;
```

the url if it is working correctly

[image]

Here it is seen in MongoDB

[image]

I am very grateful to all the people who can help me :)

Comment: There's a lot of non-related code and the question seems to be that the `onSubmit` *"does not do any action*", and that's the only function `handleFormSubmit` that is calling `postProject` that you have `fetch` call which data is never used, where do you wanna use this data is not shown. But inside of this function you need to assign a variable `const data = await savedUserResponse.json();` and use this `data`.

Comment: I understand, I already changed that part. But I also just put a console log inside the function to test and I realized that it's not even entering the postProject function :(

Comment: I noticed the `Button` is inside `form` why is that? You have a parent `Formik` and then a `form` inside that. The code is quite messy, a quick-fix would be to give the `Button` an `onClick={handleFormSubmit}` prop.

Comment: I did what you just sent me and I get an Internal Server Error, the following appears in the console: ::1 - - [10/Apr/2023:19:21:33 +0000] "POST /client/projects HTTP/1.1" 500 85

Comment: That's a server error, nothing related to the code above and it's highly a guessing-game from here. I guess your server is not started, if it is, then check the logs on the server-side.